# Ubuntu 64 bit and VM VB

Tags: virtualbox, 64-bit, youtube, virtualization

I am currently running the last stable 64 bit Ubuntu version on a VM with VirtualBox on W7 pro 64 bits.

I have tried several configurations, with some the sluginesh almost dissapeared, but I cant get to for example, play YouTube videos properly. They stutter all along.

My laptop is an i7 4th gen, with 8gb of ram and an HD 4600. So I guess its enough to serve this purpose.

Is this a general problem, or is it just me?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: With VirtualBox you can specify how much memory to give to a specific virtual machine, and how many processor cores/threads it can use.  What did you set those settings to for your Ubuntu VM?

Comment: I have 5gb and 4 cores assignated to the VM. Despite VB recommendations, I tried with 6gb and 6 cores but I had the same problem.